# flicker lightbox - download full sized images

Tags: lightbox, flickr

This is my code so far, It downloads a small 240px image. Can I get the full sized pic to create a lightbox?

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    var apikey = 'xxxxx';
    var userid = 'xxxx';
    jQuery.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key='+apikey+'&user_id='+userid+'&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    function(data){
       jQuery.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
            var purl = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_m.jpg';
            var pid = item.id;
            var container = '<img src='+ purl+' />';
            console.log(container);
           jQuery(container).appendTo('#images');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing!  You can use the API [flickr.photos.getSizes](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html) to get a list of all the sizes available.  Make one Ajax call to flickr.photos.getSizes, pick the largest one from that list, and then make your Ajax call for its URL (you won't have to stitch the URL together as you do in your original code).